How do I show a date and time in the viewing users local time?
I have a shared spreadsheet that is used by people from many different time zones around the world. On the sheet is a button that runs a Google App Script function which when finished updates a cell next to the button showing the date and time the function completed execution, set like so SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange(DATE_CELL).setValue(new Date()); This date and time is currently displayed in the time zone of the spreadsheet, United States Eastern Time. How can I format this cell show the date and time in the viewing users local time?
i.e. If the cell displays 2024-07-16 9:00 PM to a user in New York, a user in Sydney Australia should see 2024-07-17 11:00 AM and a user in London should see 2024-07-17 02:00 AM.
Note that I want to show the time in local time for whoever is looking at the sheet, not the local time of the person who last clicked the button. The person viewing the sheet may not ever need to click the button but the date and time of the last time it was clicked should still be shown to them in their local time.

I have 3 questions. 1. About a button that runs a Google App Script function, in your situation, an image or a drawing button is used? If it's so, I think that the timezone of each user can be retrieved. But, I have another question as follows.


About a shared spreadsheet that is used by people from many different time zones around the world, if user "A" and user "B" are different timezones and user "A" and user "B" run the script by clicking the button, simultaneously, what value do you want to put with updates a cell next to the button showing the date and time the function completed execution? 3. About How can I have this cell show the date and time in the viewing users local time?, if under the above condition, user "C" (different timezone from user "A" and "B") shows the Spreadsheet, what value do you want to put?


@Tanaike Note that I have added more detail to the original question, which may change your understanding of what I'm asking. Answers: 1) It is a drawing with text with a script assigned to it. 2) If the script is run twice, the last one to finish will be the one to write .setValue(new Date()) to the cell as it's the last line the script executes. 3) User A, B and C (and D, E, F, etc) should all see the date time value of the cell in their local time, even if they have never run the script themselves.

Thank you for replying. I think that I might understand the answers to my 1st and 2nd questions. About User A, B and C (and D, E, F, etc) should all see the date time value of the cell in their local time, even if they have never run the script themselves., using a single cell, you want to show a date object with multiple formats to each user with each timezone. Is my understanding correct?

@Tanaike The cell should have a single date and time, but Google Sheets should show that date and time to the user viewing it in whatever their time zone is in their Google account. Consider a shared Google Calendar: I can add an event to the calendar in my local time but whoever views the event sees the starting time in their own local time. i.e. My local time zone is Sydney, Australia. I created an event that starts at 2024-07-18 8:00 AM. A user in New York will see the start time as 2024-07-17 6:00 PM and a person in London would see the start time as 2024-07-17 11:00 PM.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. But, I would like to try to understand your reply. I apologize that I cannot understand your reply, soon.

Getting the timezone for the user is very much possible with Apps Script. However, I don't think that  displaying different data within a single cell with concurrent users is possible as this was far from what Google Sheets Intended use.

@x-x If possible, you should add a sidebar or modal for your button with <script>{your javascript to get the current time}</script> which will have access to the browser's date and time properties. Then you can pass that information to the backend using google.script.run when the button is clicked. Since Session.getTimeZone() is now deprecated, I don't think there is any other solution.

As far as I know Google Appscript doesn't have a direct way to fetch the user's timezone. However, you can use an API to fetch timezone depending on Geolocation. You can try to integrate that to your appscript.
Something like this:
Fetch location via API > parse response > extract timezone and write to cell > CreateButton > Edit button function to getTimeZone on click.
Hope this helps!
